# multiprocessing not working in PyInstaller: 3.6 and Python: 3.8.2 (conda)

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have configure multiprocessing in my python script. It is running smoothly when directly execute the file. But when I am creating exe by using PyInstaller: 3.6, The execution stuck in multiprocessing section. Below are the details

**Environment**

```
PyInstaller: 3.6
Python: 3.8.2 (conda)
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
```

**Script**

```
number_processes = 4
print("START multiprocessing")
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(number_processes)
print("INTIALIZE multiprocessing")
pool.map_async(work_function, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
print("CALLED multiprocessing")
pool.close()
print("CLOSED multiprocessing")
pool.join()
print("COMPLETED multiprocessing")
```

In console I can see up to **CLOSED multiprocessing** then script stuck. It can not complete multiprocessing. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older thread, but in case you didn't come across the answer (or for anyone else) it appears you are missing the `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` [call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support).

According to the docs:

> One needs to call this function straight after the `if __name__ == '__main__'` line of the main module.

This fixed it for me when I had a similar issue.